# 'Spring Boot Security Starter and 'Key Cloak Spring Boot Starter' secures GET correctly but not POST

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

I'm attempting to get a Spring Boot application I'm building to be protected by KeyCloak. I'm depending on the `spring-boot-starter-security` and `keycloak-spring-boot-starter` dependencies; this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/mlk5060/40bb5c1250c233d1ae7bef5864c3fb7b) shows the relevant setup. I can make a GET request to `/updates` successfully, but a `POST` request to `/updates` returns a `403` response (requests have a bearer token that is the access token retrieved for a user from KeyCloak who has the required role).

How do I setup KeyCloak and my application so that I can get consistent behaviour i.e. if GET on `updates` is allowed, POST on `updates` should be too?

Comment: I figured out what this was caused by. CSRF was active in Spring Security so, when I was submitting `POST` requests, they were being rejected. As a quick workaround (a more in-depth solution is required), I added `.and().csrf().disable()` to my `HttpSecurity` object that is passed to `SecurityConfiguration.configure()`.